# What's the best way to go about saving data to file?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an Android application that needs to store dates and time into file and then read from this file and display it in an activity. What is the best way to go about this? any common practices about this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQLite` database which allows you use of date functions.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Read here aboute `SQLite` `date` and `timestamp` functions.